# Bigquery data-lineage for CREATE TABLE AS SELECT shows nothing

Tags: google-bigquery, data-lineage

**SOLVED** All it takes is *quite a bit of patience (1 hour or so)*

I'm working through the [on the fly decryption example from strmprivacy.io](https://www.strmprivacy.io/posts/on-the-fly-decryption-bigquery/) which works fine, but the lineage tab in BigQuery shows a *stand-alone* table, instead of something derived. This is my query, and the resulting table is fine. But no lineage at all.

```sql
CREATE TABLE on_the_fly_decryption.decrypted_retail_consent_ge_1 AS
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    e.strmMeta_keyLink,
    DETERMINISTIC_DECRYPT_STRING(k.key, FROM_BASE64(e.Customer_ID), '') AS decryptedCustomerID,
    e.Customer_ID,
    ( SELECT MAX(CAST(num AS Int64)) FROM
      UNNEST(JSON_VALUE_ARRAY(e.strmMeta_consentLevels)) AS num ) max_consent
  FROM
    on_the_fly_decryption.encrypted e
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      k.keyLink,
      KEYS.KEYSET_FROM_JSON( k.encryptionKey ) key
    FROM
      on_the_fly_decryption.keys k) k
  ON e.strmMeta_keyLink = k.keyLink
)
WHERE max_consent >= 1;
```

This should work according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/concepts/about-data-lineage#auto-lineage-bq-support).

Data lineage is enabled for my project. Any hints of what (is going|am I doing) wrong?

[image]

---

P.S the query is a slightly modified one, for the UCI online retail II set instead of the earlier version, but it's pretty much equal.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it showed up after a while:
[image]

So *patience* is all it takes :-)